# Inserción de datos en Android Studio mediante Web Services y phpMyAdmin

Tags: java, android-studio, mysqli, webservice, xampp

Buenas tardes comunidad de Stack Overflow, tengo una pregunta estoy empezando a utilizar un servidor local en una de mis aplicaciones de Android Studio, junto a MySQL y phpMyAdmin. Pero tengo un problema aunque mi aplicación me devuelva el mensaje de que la inserción se realizo de manera exitosa, cuando entro al servidor local y checo la base de datos no se ve reflejada la inserción.
Adjunto codigo de mi método en Android Studio, Mis Web Services, y de la estructura de mi base de datos.

> Método donde mando a hacer el registro.

```
 public void registar(String URL){
    // Obtenemos el texto de los EditText
    String nombre = eTNombre.getText().toString();
    String apellidos = eTApellidos.getText().toString();
    String edad = eTEdad.getText().toString();

    // Se crea un objeto de la clase: String Request. Este ayuda a generar una petición al servidor local.
    StringRequest StringR = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El registro fue insertado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("nombre", nombre);
            parametros.put("apellidos", apellidos);
            parametros.put("edad", edad);
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rQueue.add(StringR);
}
```

> Set On Click donde mando a llamar al método

```
iBRegistar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        registar("http://La dirección ip de mi maquina:80/prueba/insertar.php");
    }
});
```

> Web Service: Conexión

```
<?php

$hostname = 'localhost';
$database = 'prueba';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

$conexion = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if($conexion -> connect_errno){
    echo "No fue posible establecer la conexión con la base de datos";
}

?>
```

> Web Service: Insertar

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$idEmpleado = $_POST['idEmpleado'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];

$consulta = "INSERT INTO prueba VALUES ('".$idEmpleado."', '".$nombre."', '".$apellidos."', '".$edad."')";
mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

> Imagen de la estructura de mi base de datos
> [image: Estructura de mi base de datos]

Nota: El campo idEmpleado quiero que sea auto incrementable, desconozco si eso pudiera tener algo que ver.

> Archivo "config.php" Actualizado:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'prueba';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';

// Creas la conexión
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Checkeas la conexión
if ($con->connect_error) {
  die("Error en la conexión: " . $con->connect_error);
}

// Se prepara la inserción de datos
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
}
if(isset($_POST['apellidos'])){
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
}
if(isset($_POST['edad'])){
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
}

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO empleados(nombre, apellidos, edad) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

try{
 $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $nombre, $spellidos, $edad);
 $stmt->execute();

 echo 'Insertado';
} catch(Exception $e){
 echo 'Excepcion: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
$stmt->close();
$con->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lo que quieres hacer veo ciertos detalles:

**Primero**, al hacer un `INSERT` cuyo campo `ID` es `AUTO_INCREMENT` no deberías agregarlo en tu consulta, ya que este se insertará de manera automática.

**Segundo**, en tu consulta de `INSERT` pones: `INSERT INTO prueba VALUES (etc)` lo cual no es correcto, ya que no funciona así en `MySQL`. Debes añadir los campos `INSERT INTO TABLA (nombre, apellidos, edad)`

**Tercero**, veo un error en tu **config.php** ya que pones `connecterrno` cuando debería ser así:

```
<?php
// Creas la conexión
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nombreDeTuBd", "tuUsuario", "tuContrasena");
    //Muestraremos un error en caso de que no se conecte
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: No se podido establecer la conexión. " . $e->getMessage());
  }
?>
```

**Cuarto**, para tu `insertar.php` deberías acostumbrarte a usar un bloque `try/catch` ahí puedes controlar las excepciones y te recomiendo que para estos casos manejes todo en un mismo archivo. Por lo que siguiendo con lo mencionado en el punto 3, haremos la ejecución del `insert`:

```
<?php
  //Establecemos los datos de conexión del servidor
  try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nombreDeTuBd", "tuUsuario", "tuContrasena");
    //Muestraremos un error en caso de que no se conecte
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: No se podido establecer la conexión. " . $e->getMessage());
  }

  // Establecemos la función de insert
  try{
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
    $edad = $_POST["edad"];

    // Creamos el insert con parámetros
    $sql = "INSERT INTO prueba (nombre, apellidos, edad) VALUES (:nom, :ap, :ed)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    // Asocio los parámetros a los campos del html
    $stmt->bindParam(':nom', $nombre);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ap', $apellidos);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ed', $edad);

     //Ejecutmos l insert
     $stmt->execute();
     echo "Insertado";
  } catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: No se ha podido insertar el registro: $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
  }
  //Cerramoa la conexión
  unset($pdo);
?>
```

Al utilizar `?` lo que hacemos es parametrizar la `query`. Al usar `ssi` especificamos el tipo de valor que contiene el campo, en este caso `string, string, int`.

**Quinto**, tu `response` nos devuelve algo. Lo mejor que puede hacer es controlar desde ahí la respuesta:

```
StringRequest StringR = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains("Insertado") || response.equals("Insertado"){ 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El registro fue insertado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    },//resto código
```

Comment: Hola Franqo Balsamo, agradezco mucho todas tus observaciones ya tome cartas en el asunto y reescribí el codigo del Web Service, en un archivo nuevo llamado config.php, solo me quedo un detalle en el codigo y es el siguiente: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ex' (T_STRING), expecting '|' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Me he percatado de un error de escritura en mí código, he corregido el punto 4. Dime si te ha funcionado el cambio. El error es que escribí `(Exception ex)` y es `(Exception $ex)`. También había un error dónde ponía `$e->` y es `$ex->` espero te sirva :)

Comment: Si, el problema estaba en la excepción, se maneja como variable la ex: ($ex), pero ahora solo tengo el siguiente detalle: Notice: Undefined variable: servername in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\config.php on line 4. Dice que no tengo las 4 variables definidas pero al definirlas arriba me marca lo siguiente: Notice: Undefined index: nombre y Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool Y estos errores los desconozco.

Comment: Vale, he actualizado la respuesta. He utilizado `PDO` ya que con `mysqli` no me llevo muy bien, me confirmas si te funciona

Comment: La verdad no, la verdad me regresare en este caso a mysqli, pero voy a seguir buscando como solucionar esos errores.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu archivo php completo? Veamos de poder solucionarlo

Comment: Con gusto, pero creo que ya lo solucione, al abrir el archivo en el local host, me devuelve el mensaje de Insertado. Pero dejo los enlaces con los cuales me apoye y mi codigo: https://www.srcodigofuente.es/aprender-php/error-undefined-index-variable y para el Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool: En la consulta SQL, estaba tratando de insertar los datos en el nombre de la base de datos y no el de la tabla.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130846/discussion-between-victor-manuel-and-franqo-balsamo).